# SOAP client SAAJ

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, soap, saaj

I am relatively new to SOAP and wanted to write a SOAP client in JAVA. I figured out that the WSDL has a lot of other crap and as I use just one service out of it, hence SAAJ would be the shortest way. The first WSDL I got was RPC encoded and did not support SSL connections (http link). The call I made was this:

```
String request = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:urn=\"urn:AxessInterface\">"
                + "   <soapenv:Header/>"
                + "   <soapenv:Body>"
                + "      <urn:getModemFromACS soapenv:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">"
                + "<ModemIDMACAddressChoice xsi:type=\"urn:ModemIDMACAddressChoiceStruct\">"
                + "            <ModemID xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">"
                + modemId
                + "</ModemID>"
                + "         </ModemIDMACAddressChoice>"
                + "      </urn:getModemFromACS>"
                + "   </soapenv:Body>"
                + "</soapenv:Envelope>";
```

The new WSDL that I have is I guess NOT RPC encoded (it does not have that "style=rpc" tag anywhere) and the link is SSL enabled (https with one way authentication). The style is "document" in this WSDL.

I have a couple of issues:

1. My soap call doesnt work. I modified it to be:

   String request = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:urn=\"urn:AxessInterface\">"
                   + "   "
                   + "   "
                   + "      "
                   + "         "
                   + "            "
                   + modemId
                   + ""
                   + "         "
                   + "      "
                   + "   "
                   + "";

I am not sure why the code cannot be displayed, i removed the line "soapenv:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" . With this i get a SOAPFault with message: "list index out of range"

1. Can someone tell me how to add that truststore to my SOAP client? (I use System.setProperty but I am not sure if this is the best way to go).

Comment: Why on earth are you doing your soap calls in such a hard way? I mean manually constructing the SOAP request. Use CXF to read the WSDL and generate the client side code for you. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Namphibian : The WSDL on the backend is weird, it initially didnot work with CXF (Due to it being RPC encoded). I got it changed and now will try with CXF.